# Does $S(x) = x+1$ always hold in Peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

In some books, they seem to implicitly say that $S(x) = x+1$ holds always in Peano arithmetic. But does it really hold in all cases, even in non-standard ones? The standard model of course satisfies this, but non-standard ones don't seem obvious.

Also, in Peano arithmetic, some books also say that $0<1$ all the times. Is this true for all non-standard models of Peano arithmetic?

If all these are true, is this solely due to axiom schema of induction?

Comment: Yes, the first does hold in all models, that is part of the definition of $+$. And $0\lt 1$ sort of holds, or at least the formal version holds (usually the language does not contain a binary predicate symbol $\lt$, nor a constant symbol $1$.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that $1$ is a shorthand for $S(0)$. Our language only contains the symbols $0,S,+,\cdot$ and no symbol for $1$.

The axioms for addition tell us that $x+0=x$ and $S(x+y)=x+S(y)$. Therefore we have:

$$S(x)=S(x+0)=x+S(0)=x+1.$$

As you can see I didn't use induction, at all.

Comment: Oh now I get it. I at first thought $S(0)=1$ is not mentioned in Peano arithmetic, then realized I can derive it from axioms... :)

Comment: Jack, there's nothing to derive. We **define** the symbol $1$ to be a placeholder for the term $S(0)$. Note that $1,2,3,\ldots$ are not part of our languages, much like $\varnothing$ is not part of the language of $\sf ZFC$. We just add this symbol to the language as a way to improve readability by humans.